# ArcScene Export to 3D Webscene polygon issue?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, 3d-analyst, arcscene, web-scene

I have been putting together a 3D basemap for our campus, Washington State University, and have been trying to share my model using the export to 3d web scene arcToolbox tool.  For the most part is has worked pretty well except for my StreetPavement feature class (polygon).  For some reason, blank spaces in between polygons are getting filled.  In other words, the areas that would be filled by my LandscapeArea polygon class are being filled with gray polygons.  I have attached a screenshot to help illustrate.  If I turn off the StreetPavement layer in the web scene viewer it looks fine.  The strange this is that the LandscapeArea class doesn't experience this same phenomenon.  I have tried about twenty different things to the StreetPavement class, but always end up with the same result.  For example:

- Merging all of the LandscapeArea class, then performing a clip on the StreetPavement
- Creating a new featureclass, then coping the features from the StreetPavement into it.
- Creating a raster layer from the StreetPavement class then displaying it in the model.  (This sort of works but doesn't look that great)

I have even gone so far as to copy the features within the StreetPavement class and copying them into the LandscapeArea class.  The result ends up looking the same.  So I know the issue has to do something with the polygons in the StreetPavement class, but I have no idea what it is or what else to try.

Dark gray area filling in between polygons in the StreetPavement Class.
[image]

Without the StreetPavement Layer turned on.
[image]

Everything looks great in ArcScene.
[image]

Comment: Just an idea, worth running the pavement data through the check geometry tool to see if you have any malformed geometries?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately I have already tried that as well.  After closer inspection it appears that there are a few (2 or 3) polygons in the landscape data that exhibit the same behavior.  As well as a few in the streetpavement data that don't.  :(

Comment: I have narrowed down the issue to doughnut polygons, or polygons that have a hole for another polygon inside of it.  If I cut a piece out of the outside polygon so it is no longer enclosed it renders correctly.  It would take a ton cutting of the streetpavement data to get it to render properly.  There has got to be a setting for the webscene somewhere or a process to run to do this automatically.  Does anyone have any ideas?